# Is there an alternative PCI wireless adapter equivalent to a PCI-E Archer T9E?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, desktop-computer, pci-express, pci

I just bought the [TP-Link AC 1900 Wireless Duel Band PCI Express Adapter (Archer T9E)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833704241) and when I looked inside my computer, I noticed my enormous graphics card was covering my only PCI-Express port.

Thusly I only have a regular old PCI port to work with.

I've done some research and there are [PCI-E to PCI converters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0037ECAM2) (but based on user feedback they seem pretty shady and difficult to install).

Its also hard to look up PCI wireless adapters because most of the results are for PCIE.

I would greatless appreciate any suggestions for a similar wireless card to the Archer T9E. (Please no usb)

Comment: The PCI buss doesn't have the same speeds as pci-e 1x, the card would not function at the sames speed. you'd be better off with a basic pci one.

Comment: @cengbrecht I figured. Is there one you would recommend with some pretty good specs? Or would I be better off getting a USB. Its for gaming.

Comment: USB3 would be the best

Comment: What's your motherboard? *Typically* 2 slot cards block a PCI port, not a PCIe port.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Here is a pic: http://www.gigabyte.com/fileupload/product/2/4305/6448_big.jpg This orientation triggers me.

Comment: .... The fools. That's a pretty dumb layout.

Comment: I wonder if you could thread a riser underneath the video card. You'd still need to figure out where to slot the wireless card....

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Not really too sure about my confidence in doing something like that. I think I'll just go with a USB3 for now until I upgrade to a DDR4 in the near future... Not going with gigabyte again, I'll tell you that much lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few options here, not in order of most likely:

1. Check if you really only have one PCI-e connector. Not all of them are the huge x16 slots often used for graphics cards. A PCI-e x1 or x4 might be somewhere on the motherboard.
2. Replace the motherboard with one with more PCI-e slots. (Best for future proofing. Most work. Relative expensive).
3. Use another bus. Thunderbolt is plenty fast. Or USB. (USB3 should be fast enough for most practical wireless speeds, though barele so).
4. Or, if network speeds are most important (e.g. a fileserver rather than a gaming PC): Remove the graphics card. Is needed add a PCI graphic card.
5. Lastly (and my prefered workaround bar replacing the MB): Get a wireless access point. Basically 'reverse-use' a wireless station. Make a wireless connection, bridge that to wired Ethernet. Plug the wired Ethernet cable into the NIC on the motherboard.

Comment: Ive found many 'range extenders' also act as wireless clients with ethernet out. If you're getting an AP, make sure it does client or bridged mode.

Comment: USB3 supports up to 5Gbps, more than enough for wifi...

Comment: Up to 5Gbit/sec theorerical max. Wiresless's theoretical max is now about 1900Mbit/sec (and yes, I know you only reach that in labs, but at home I do get an 866MHz connection with the AC devices in the living room. In which case USB 3.0 gen 1 would be a bottleneck).